# mongodb query with multiple conditions, filtering with $gte

Tags: mongodb

I need a little help with a query in mongodb, I made a search here and google about how to achieve this but no lucky

I have this example of data:

```
{
    "retval": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$id": "54f6d4f20ae9d042358b4ca0"
            },
            "origin": "direct",
            "name": "Rafaela",
            "email": "rafa@hotmail.com",
            "ddd": "71",
            "phone": "93660490",
            "message": "Quero simula\u00e7\u00e3o desse cons\u00f3rcio e outras possibilidades para o mesmo carro selecionado",
            "receive_copy": "true",
            "dealer_id": {
                "$id": "5387b7e05717d766e6e32f1b"
            },
            "dealership": {
                "$id": "532afbf56ee011a9bfb07428"
            },
            "type": "consortium",
            "status": "pending",
            "date_month": 3,
            "date_year": 2015,
            "date_day": 4,
            "date": {
                "sec": 1425462514,
                "usec": 427000
            },
            "dealer_name": "Lauro de Freitas"
        },
```

And I need to filter this with messages from year 2021 (field date_year), I tried the parameter $gte but it return zero, what I'm doing wrong?

```
db.Messages.find({"type":"consortium"},{"date_year": {$gte: 2021 },{name:1,dealer_name:1,date_day:1,date_month:1,date_year:1}).toArray()
```

Comment: you have passed date_year condition in second parameter it should be in first, `find({"type":"consortium", "date_year": {$gte: 2021 } }, {name:1,dealer_name:1,date_day:1,date_month:1,date_year:1})`

Comment: but it still returning nothing :(

db.Messages.find({"date_year": {$gte: 2021 }},{"type":"consortium"},{name:1,dealer_name:1,date_day:1,date_month:1,date_year:1}).toArray()

Comment: 1) make sure the collection name `Messages` is correct, 2) make sure you have `date_year` year greater than or 2021, otherwise looks good

Comment: "retval.date_year" is the field but best to use $filter here to get only the messages you need not the whole document

Answer (score 0):

Aggregation filter example [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q_MV7DWbzKI)

Code:

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
   {
     $match: {
       "retval.date_year": {
       $gte: 2014
     }
    }
   },
  {
   $project: {
      retval: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$retval",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $gte: [
              "$$item.date_year",
              2014
            ]
          }
        }
      }
     }
   }
  ])
```

explained:

1. You match only the documents with with the desired year in messages inside retval array.
2. Project only those messages from desired year.

Hint: It is best to create index on "retval.date_year"  field for best results.